# Blacklisted applications and APIs can still be invoked

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I have a distributed setup of WSO2 APIM on Kubernetes. I have deployed the pizzashack api.

From the admin portal, I have blacklisted both the Default Application and the Pizzashack API. I am however still able to invoke the Pizzashack API from the WSO2 API Store from the Default application.

I do not see any errors/warnings in the logs of the individual component.

It seems that the throttling policies are not being applied. What might be the cause of this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

What is your port number?? for HTTPS default port number is 9443. If you have changed port then change the port in /conf/JNDI.properties file.

Comment: How is the port number change related to this issue? Can you please elaborate further